# How to remove the first piece of data from an array extracted from PHP, displayed with SMARTY?

Tags: php, html, arrays, smarty

I'm trying to display the array below with SMARTY as a HTML table. Everything is perfect however the first row of the table is displayed as:

ARRAY ARRAY ARRAY

Then the data follows correctly after this as wanted. Obviously I don't wanted to display the above.

The below is the array exported from the PHP file: The array consists of three arrays hence the three columns.

```
array ( 0 => array ( ), 1 => array ( 0 => array ( ), 1 => '2160', 2 => '63800', 3 => '175820', 4 => '234823', 5 => '253080', 6 => '256680', 7 => '258760', 8 => '258840', 9 => '259560', 10 => '258480', 11 => '258550', 12 => '258660', 13 => '258480', 14 => '258300', 15 => '256140', 16 => '257770', 17 => '255960', 18 => '255780', 19 => '252520', 20 => '253980', 21 => '252540', 22 => '250560', 23 => '245700', 24 => '253080', 25 => '248580', 26 => '248860', 27 => '249660', 28 => '246780', ), 2 => array ( 0 => array ( ), 1 => '2150', 2 => '63800', 3 => '175420', 4 => '234843', 5 => '253080', ), 3 => array ( 0 => array ( ), 1 => '2110', 2 => '63800', 3 => '175820', 4 => '234823', 5 => '252180', 6 => '256680', ), )
```

The below is how I'm displaying the current table:

```
<table id="t01">
 <tr>

 <th>Blank</th>
   {foreach from=$numFlocks item=foo}
      <th>Flock {$foo}</th>
   {/foreach}
 </tr>

 {section loop=$flock[1] name=unit}
  <tr>
    {foreach from=$flock item=foo}
        <td>{$foo[unit]}</td>
    {/foreach}
  </tr>
  {/section}

 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to display this first row.

```
{section loop=$flock[1] name=unit}
  <tr {if $smarty.section.unit.first}style="display:none"{/if}>
    {foreach from=$flock item=foo}
        <td>{$foo[unit]}</td>
    {/foreach}
  </tr>
{/section}
```